# How does one use multiple filters in the styles and computed tabs of the Chrome DevTools inspector?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In the **Filter** field of the **Styles** and **Computed** tab of the inspector in Chrome DevTools, how does one use multiple ORed filters like `width|height` so I can see more styles at one time? I've tried every character I could think of that might be used and searched the docs and elsewhere online. There's so many properties, it would be really useful to see a related set like the usual box-model ones or flex-box related ones.

Comment: Let me know if you ever find out a way to do this.  I, too, am very interested in doing this.

Comment: Ditto... just tried all the chars I could think of like you did, then decided to try Google. lol

Answer (score 0):

The filter field in the styles and computed tab of the inspector does not accept an array of elements or even regex. It only works when every character typed matches.